# How can I make a Date to jump every n seconds?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate, nstimeinterval

I want to make the date to change one day every "n" seconds, like a time machine. I have this code but nothing happens, any help will be appreciated.
this is the code: no issues, no error ... no tomorrow date!

```
-(IBAction)jumpDate

{

NSDateFormatter *dateFormater = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormater setDateFormat:@"dd MMMM yyyy  h:mm:ss"];  //dateFormater.dateStyle   =NSDateFormatterLongStyle; //USA date style MMMM-dd-yyyy
[dateFormater setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"CDT"]];

NSDate *todayDate = [[NSDate alloc]init];

[gregDate setText : [dateFormater stringFromDate:todayDate]];

[NSString stringWithFormat:@"dd MMMM yyyy", dayCount];

dayCount++;

if (dayCount >= 365)

{
    dayCount = 365;

    [timerDate invalidate];

}
}
//and the timer

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

NSDateFormatter *dateFormater = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init]autorelease];
[dateFormater setDateFormat:@"dd MMMM yyyy"];

NSTimeInterval secondsPerDay = 86400 ; // = 24 * 60 * 60

NSDate *today = [[[NSDate alloc]init]autorelease];
NSDate *tomorrow;
tomorrow = [today dateByAddingTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)secondsPerDay];

 [gregDate setText : [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@ ",tomorrow]];

 dayCount = 1;
 timerDate=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self    selector:@selector(jumpDate)userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
NSDate *todayDate = [[NSDate alloc]init];
```

with this line:

```
NSDate *todayDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:dayCount * 86400];
```

Comment: I will try that and let you know if there any difference. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have 3 questions, not all directly related to your question.

1. Why `-(IBAction)jumpDate` is an IBAction, if you are calling this method from your code you should changed it to `(void)` and if an IBAction need to call that, call it from an other method that would be the action for that button.
2. Is there a missing space in your code before `userInfo` in this call :
   `timerDate=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self    selector:@selector(jumpDate)userInfo:nil repeats:YES];`
3. Did you verified that your IBOutlet are all set properly? I've stop counting the times I've forgot that.

---

```
[gregDate setText : [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@ ",tomorrow]];
```

What is gregDate? is it an IBOutlet pointing to a UILabel?
And you've probably verified this, but, that call retunr a valid string?

---

You should not call your `IBAction` method from your timer, for 2 reasons,
1. I really think it's bad design, it's introducing confusion on the role of this method since it's also call from a timer.
2. The method signature doesn't match the one NSTimer needs

> aSelector:
>   The message to send to target when the timer fires. The selector must have the following signature:
>   - (void)timerFireMethod:(NSTimer*)theTimer

This text come from the [NSTimer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nstimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) class reference.

Comment: I used IBAction button because I want to start the date jumping when the user push the button. The timer is setting identical to the other timer and the other ones are working fine. IBOutlet connections are all set. thanks

Comment: gregDate means Gregorian date just to set a difference, I will have Julian and Mayan, so I used to identificate. the label shows tomorrow date but I want that date to change every n secs using the timer.